# Suppose 3 people are each dealt 2 cards from a standard deck of playing cards

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose 3 people are each dealt 2 cards from a standard deck of playing cards. In how many ways can the cards be dealt (order doesn’t matter) so that somebody gets at least one ace? (Answer: 727,830,720)

Here is my answer:

3 people ,each gets 2 cards: A = $\frac{52*51}{2}*\frac{50*49}{2}*\frac{48*47}{2}$/6

no one has ace: B =  $\frac{48*47}{2}*\frac{46*45}{2}*\frac{44*43}{2}$/6

Final answer is A-B

but it is not equal to the given answer, can someone tell me where I got wrong? Thank you!

I divided them by 6 because I think the order of people does not matter so I divide the number of ways these 3 people can be ordered but it seems that the right answer didn't divide this 6.

Comment: Are you saying that $727,830,720$ is wrong?  That is the number that your calculations give.

Comment: @Taussig I get four times that? 2,911,322,880

Comment: because you divide by 2 only once

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((52!%2F46!)%2F2)+-+((48!%2F42!)%2F2)

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((52!%2F46!)%2F8)+-+((48!%2F42!)%2F8)

Comment: @johny Oh yes there you go then thanks

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I have edited the question. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: The order of the people does matter.  It matters whether Alexander receives $7\clubsuit, \color{red}{5\diamondsuit}$ and Bruce receives $J\spadesuit, \color{red}{4\heartsuit}$ or whether Alexander receives $J\spadesuit, \color{red}{4\heartsuit}$ and Bruce receives  $7\clubsuit, \color{red}{5\diamondsuit}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you! I got it.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.